# Reading user permissions in Google Analytics via API - not working on property level

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am trying to read out the list of users, incl the user permissions, using the API call documented at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountUserLinks/list

I get the list of users as expected, but not the permissions. (Actually, for "some" users the permissions is listed, but not for the most)

The GA setup has a number of properties, and the users have permissions set on property level in most cases.

My guess is that the "property level permissions" is not reported properly through the API response for the users which in the UI/console have their permissions listed as "None (user has permissions on a lower level)"

As the next intended step is not only to read out the user list, incl permissions, but also do scripted CRUD operations I'd like to understand what the "intended way" to deal with this via the API is.

Anyone that is working with CRUD operations of users via the Analytics management API?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, finally I found the API call https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webpropertyUserLinks/list which solves the problem.

(Sorry for not RTFM, but it is actually a bit confusing when this API call is at the end of API list, and the other call is in the beginning...)